# Class type of reference and the actual class type, which decides which method to call?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

The title may be misleading but as a non-native i couldn't figure out a better one.

Say i have two classes, `Dog` and `Fox` :

```
public class Dog {
    public String bark() {
        return "Wuff";
    }
    public String play(Dog d) {
        return "Wuff" + d.bark();
    }
}


public class Fox extends Dog {
    public String bark() {
        return "Ringding" ;
    }
    public String play(Fox f) {
        return "Ringding" + f.bark();
    }
}
```

And i create some instances as well call some methods

```
Fox foxi = new Fox();
Dog hybrid = new Fox();
System.out.println(hybrid.play(foxi)); // Output number 1
System.out.println(foxi.play(hybrid)); // Output number 2
```

For the 1. Ouput I expected `"RingdingRingding"` because `hybrid` actually is a reference to an instance of the `Dog`, even if the reference has a type of `Dog`
it still refers to an `Fox` object, but still i got this output :

> WuffRingding

The second one i got the same problem, since `foxi` is an instance of `Fox` and `hybrid` is actually an instance of `Fox` (no matter what reference, right ?), the ouput should be `"RingdingRingding"` but then again, i got :

> WuffRingding

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: The significant thing is that `Fox.play(Fox)` doesn't override `Dog.play(Dog)`. Because the type of `hybrid` is `Dog`, the `play(Dog)` overload is invoked.

Comment: @AndyTurner hi Andy, thanks for your answer. Still when it comes to typecasting, the actuall type does matter right ? Let say i cast (Dog) to an instance of Fox and call the bark method, still it will be the method in class Fox, right ? Im little confused between reference and casting..

Comment: The method to be invoked is determined at compile time, not runtime. So, if you pass a reference to a `Dog` to a method, the overload taking a `Dog` is invoked - even if that refers to a `Fox` at runtime.

Comment: @AndyTurner i dont really get what you say. Then again why when i typecast (Dog) to an object of Fox, the method bark() in Fox will still be called because here it matters what the actual type of the object. Do you have some keywords so i can learn more about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important things for method invocations.

You have two times : the compilation time and the runtime.
And rules are not the same between these two times.

- at compile time the compiler has to definite statically which exact signature of method is called to compile fine. 
  This binding is static as the compiler doesn't matter of the concrete instance on which the method is invoked and it is the same thing for the parameters passed to the method. 
  The compiler doesn't rely on the effective types as at runtime the effective types could change during the execution flow.
  So the compiler searches among available methods for a declared type, which is the more specific method according to the declared types of parameters passed to it.
- at runtime an instance method from a class or from another one will be used according to the effective instance on which the method is invoked.
  But the invoked method has to respect the signature specified at compile time.

1)For the first case :

```
Fox foxi = new Fox();
Dog hybrid = new Fox();
System.out.println(hybrid.play(foxi)); // Output number 1
```

- First time (compîle time) :

For a Dog instance, the compiler has to find the most specific method `play()` with as parameter a variable with the Fox declared type.

In Dog class, a single method `play()` with a compatible signature exist :

```
public String play(Dog d) {
```

So this signature is used for the binding : `String play(Dog d)`.

About the `bark()` method, it is much obvious as there is only one bark() method signature . 
So we have no ambiguity on the method that is bound at compile time

- Second time (runtime) :

At runtime the `String play(Dog d)` method of the concrete instance is invoked. 
The `hybrid` variable refers to an instance of Fox but Fox doesn't override 
`String play(Dog d)`. Fox defines a play() method but with another signature :

```
public String play(Fox f) {
```

So the JVM invokes the  `public String play(Dog d) {` method of Dog.
And then it invokes the method of the effective type of `d` when `d.bark()` is executed and `d` refers to a `Fox` instance.

So "WuffRingding" is output.

---

2) For the second case :

```
Fox foxi = new Fox();
Dog hybrid = new Fox();
System.out.println(foxi.play(hybrid)); // Output number 2
```

- First time (compile time) :

For a `Fox` instance, the compiler has to find the most specific method `play()` with as parameter a variable with the `Dog` declared type.

In `Fox` class, two `play()` methods with a compatible parameter exist :

```
public String play(Dog d) { // inherited from the parent class

public String play(Fox f) { // declared in Fox
```

The compiler has to choose the more specific method for the call context of the method
It identifies a method  more specific that the other one for a `Dog` declared type parameter : `public String play(Dog d)`.
So the compiler binds the `play()` method invocation to `public String play(Dog d)` when it compiles the class.

- Second time (runtime) :

At runtime the `String play(Dog d)` method of the concrete instance is invoked. 
As for the first case, the `foxi` variable refers to an instance of Fox but Fox doesn't override `String play(Dog d)`. 
So the JVM invokes the  `public String play(Dog d)` method of Dog.
And then it invokes the method of the effective type of `f` when `f.bark()` is executed and `f` refers to a `Fox` instance.

So "WuffRingding" is again output.

---

To avoid this kind of surprise you should add `@Override`
in the methods designed to override a parent class method :
For example :

```
@Override
public String play(Fox f) {
    return "Ringding" + f.bark();
}
```

If the method doesn't override effectively a `play(Fox f)` method in the hierarchy, the compiler will complain about it.

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer. Still  tried some thing like :
Dog a = (Dog) foxi;
a.bark();

Output is still "Ringding" even if "a" a reference of type "Dog" is, can you explain why ?

Comment: You are welcome :) Re read this part of my answer : "About the bark() method, it is much obvious as there is only one bark() method signature . 
So we have no ambiguity on the method that is bound at compile time". It means that at compile time the unique `bark()` method was bound in the compiled class. And at runtime, the JVM uses the bound method (`bark()`) of the effective instance on which the method is invoked on.

Comment: i get it now, many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here in your case The `play` method is overloaded not overridden.

When you do this `Dog d = new Fox()` The reference of `Dog` will call the method of class `Dog` only until and unless the methods of `Dog` class are overridden by `Fox` class. When the methods are overridden invoking of such methods is resolved at runtime but the invoking of overloaded methods is resolved at compile time.

Read static polymorphism and run-time polymorphism for further clearance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the thing which causes your confusion is that you think the play-method in the subclass `Fox` **overrides** the play-method of the superclass, while it actually just **overloads** it.

If you change the parameter type of `f` in the play-method of the Fox-class to type `Dog`, the output will be "RingdingRingding" both times for the reasons you analyzed in your question, because in this case the play-method correctly overrides the superclass-method.

Let's look into the case with the overloaded play-methods in more detail:

```
hybrid.play(foxi)
```

The compiler looks at the declared static type of `hybrid` which is `Dog`. `foxi` is declared as `Fox`. Therefore, the compiler looks for a play-method in class `Dog` which expects one parameter of static type `Fox`. It is not successful, because there is only a play-method which expects one parameter of static type `Dog`. However, the compiler will still pick this method for invocation in the end, because `Dog` is a superclass of `Fox`.

```
foxi.play(hybrid)
```

The compiler looks at the declared static type of `foxi` which is `Fox`.
`hybrid` is declared as `Dog`. Therefore, the compiler looks for a play-method in class `Fox` which expects one parameter of static type `Dog`. There are two play-methods in class `Fox` the compiler can choose from: `play(Fox f)` and the inherited overloaded method `play(Dog d)`. `play(Fox f)` is not a valid choice since this method expects one parameter of type `Fox`, while `hybrid` is declared as `Dog`. This means the compiler will again pick the `play(Dog d)` method, which is declared in class `Dog`, like for the previous statement.

The reason why the compiler doesn't allow you to override `play(Fox f)` with  `play(Dog d)` is the following: Imagine it was allowed and someone would do this:

```
Dog doggo = new Dog();
hybrid.play(doggo);
```

Now, the overriden `play(Fox f)` method would be called with an input-parameter of type `Dog` at runtime which doesn't work, because the implemenatation of 
`play(Fox f)` expects that the `f` is not only a `Dog`, but a more specialized `Fox`.

To avoid overload/override confusion annotate methods which should override superclass-methods with `@Override`. The compiler will refuse to compile your code if a with `@Override` annotated method actually does not override a superclass method.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for determining which method will be invoked are [pretty complicated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), but I'll try to summarize them for this cases here.

Firstly, for `hybrid.play(foxi)`:

1. Determine Class or Interface to Search

   `hybrid` has type `Dog`, so the `Dog` interface will be searched for methods. This means that only methods you have defined on `Dog` will even possibly be invoked. These are:

   ```
   bark()
   play(Dog)
   ```
2. Determine Method Signature

   You are invoking the `play` method, with a parameter of type `Fox`. `Fox` is a subtype of `Dog`, so the `play(Dog)` method is matched.

So, that method is the one invoked.

Next, for `foxi.play(hybrid)`:

1. Determine Class or Interface to Search

   `foxi` has type `Fox`, so the `Fox` interface will be searched for methods. The available methods are:

   ```
   bark()
   play(Dog)
   play(Fox)
   ```

   Notice that `play(Fox)` doesn't override `play(Dog)`: they don't have the same method signature, so `play(Fox)` is merely an overload.
2. Determine Method Signature

   You are invoking the `play` method, with a parameter of type `Dog`. As such, the `play(Dog)` method is the one invoked, since that is the only one which matches.

   It doesn't matter that `hybrid` has a runtime type `Fox`: this selection of the method to be invoked happens at compile time.

   Hence, `play(Dog)`, not `play(Fox)`, is invoked.